# Can I create osX java application bundle that open multiple instances of program?

Tags: java, macos, bundle

I wonder if it is possible to specify an osX application bundle .plist key that allows for opening new instances of a program when i click "open with" in Finder?
I have created a simple text editor in java and want to open multiple instances when clicking on different text files.
The current behaviour is that the currently open instance of program is destroyed and the new is opened.
Is there a way to handle this in the Mac OSX with the ApplicationListener interface?
In windows "open with" opens a new instance of the program.
/Andreas